# matlab - imread and imshow on very large jp2

Tags: matlab, jpeg2000

i am working with a very large jp2 (jpeg2000) file,
and need to view it using the imshow function.

given that the jp2 file has several levels scale (by wavelet
decomposition levels), i thought that i will be able to load
it and show it, without the need to load the entire file size (several GB),
much like loading an RSET file.

i've tried loading the file and showing it with imshow,
but Matlab crashes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If MATLAB crashes I guess it's because you went out of memory. To work with big image files, I'd suggest you to take a look at `imageDatastore` objects http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagedatastore-object.html

Comment: @BillBokeey, the link says this object is used for a set of images in which every image in itself fits in the memory. in my case the image does not.

Comment: Exactly, in your example the set of images will be slices of your original image which doesn't fit in memory. I only know it works for big data files but, after all, images are only matrices of doubles so it should work aswell

Comment: Try `ds=datastore('YourImagePath','Type','Image');`, what's the result?

Comment: @BillBokeey, apparently it needs Matlab R2014... I have Matlab R2013 :(